# Azure pipelines output variable cross stage

Tags: azure-pipelines

I wanna use at the output of a command as a cross stage variable in Azure Pipeline but I can't figure it out how to do it. I have this code:

```
parameters:
  - name: mainPackage
    type: string

stages:
- stage: Setup
  jobs:
  - job: Variables
    steps:

    - task: npmAuthenticate@0
      inputs:
        workingFile: './.npmrc'

    - powershell: |
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=version;isOutput=true]npm view ${{ parameters.mainPackage }} version"
        Write-Host "$(version)"
      name: Version
```

And as the second stage I have:

```
- stage: Other
  dependsOn: Setup
  variables:
    version: $[ stageDependencies.Setup.Variables.outputs['Variables.version'] ]
  jobs:
    - job: Check
  steps: 
      - script: echo ${{ variables.version }}
```

I tried also other variants with bash script but I can't get it to work.

Most of the times I get this: line 1: `stageDependencies.Setup.Variables.outputs['Variables.version'] : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".Setup.Variables.outputs['Variables.version'] ")`

Comment: The indentation is wrong, this is not a valid Azure Pipeline definition

Comment: Also, are you using Azure DevOps Server (self-hosted) or cloud version? In case of Server: Which version?

Comment: The definition seems wrong but it's a template yaml - do it's a bit different. The pipeline runs fine until I get the invalid arithmetic operator error. It's a cloud hosted instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few problems here:

Replace this:
`Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=version;isOutput=true]npm view ${{ parameters.mainPackage }} version"` with this:

```
$npmVersion = npm view ${{ parameters.mainPackage }} version
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=version;isOutput=true]$npmVersion"
```

else you will be setting the variable to the command of getting the version and not the actual version.

In the second stage (Other), to use the variable you just got out, use `echo $(version)` instead of `echo ${{ variables.version }}`

Tested on my own and it works.